# Jmeter - Getting Error when recording in Thread Group

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I am trying to record Https request.

When i record under HTTP(s) Test Script Recorder it records and i can see Request/response under View Results tree without errors.

When i try to do record same scenario but under Thread Group , it gives me error (Error is thrown by the application).
Application Error - An error was encountered   There was an error on the page. Click "Go Back" to go to previous page or click "Home" to go to homepage.

Structure is : Test Plan -> Thread Group -> Recording Controller

In my application while recording it starts with Login Page(SSO Login page) -> Home Page -> Search Page -> On this page i search something and want to capture its response time taken for search.

I think problem is ViewState and EventValidation not getting passed ? Is their a way i can pass it to the page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems problem with the correlation. You need to find the dynamic parameters like ViewState and event validation.

1. Record to scripts and compare them to check the dynamic parameter with any sniffing tool like fiddler. If you already aware then ignore this step.
2. Usually, you get the required parameter before the final call is made. So, you need to find the occurrence where you are getting the required parameters in response and capture using PostProcessor.
3. Then, pass the captured parameters in the required request.

EX;-Below is for more clarification. Follow same for all dynamic parameters.
TestPlan

--Request1-->[PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors)(Like RegEx or any other) to capture viewState

--Request2--Pass the captured viewState value to this request.

Comment: I have debug web application using fidler. And I found that there are two hidden parameters: ViewState and EventValidation. Then i used Regular Expression Extractor for for these two parameters. But in the response data tab of View Result Tree, i am getting below error. "The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted. Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. "

Comment: Once you have capture it then pass it to the required request. There may be possibilities that viewstate may change for every page. So, there may be multiple places where you have to capture it and pass it. Ex. 1 page --One View State, 2nd page--2nd View state...So, capturing first view state and passing to all will not work. Since, error is for the state, might best guess is viewstate needs to be correlated multiple places.

Comment: PostProcessor -> CSS Selctor Extractor helped to pass value of Viewstate & Event Validation